# Making MineCraft In 2D

Tags: collision-detection

I am making a 2D game that is based on Minecraft. I made the terrain but I just don't know how to do the collision between the player. I tied to draw the rectangles with a for loop and detect collision between the player player and the rectangles but when I run it it only detects collision between the last rectangle on the map and the player. Please help.

[image]

This is my code.

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
private BufferedImage player;
private BufferedImage block;
private BufferedImage dbImage;
private ImageIcon player2;
private Graphics dbg;
private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
private double velX = 5.0f;
private double velY = 5.0f;
public Rectangle rectangle;
public Rectangle rectangle2;
private int[] xb = {0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650};
private int[] yb = {0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650};
//
public Gameplay(){
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    dbImage = (BufferedImage) createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    repaint();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    try {
        player = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Player.png"));
        block = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Grass.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    drawBlock(g);
    g.drawImage(player, x, y, this);
    rectangle2 = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50);
    if(rectangle2.intersects(rectangle)){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

public void drawBlock(Graphics g){
    for(int first = 0; first < 10; first++){
        for(int second = 0; second < 10; second++){
            g.drawImage(block, xb[first], yb[second], this);
            rectangle = new Rectangle(xb[first], yb[second], 50, 50);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        y += -velY;
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        y += velY;
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        x += -velX;
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        x += velX;
    }


}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
     }
```

Comment: Remember that we've never seen your game or its codebase before, so spending a few extra sentences to help get us oriented (like what is "the player player" or "the rectangle" and what collision detection strategies are you trying to use?) can help you get better, more accurate and useful answers, faster.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to GD.SE. Please use the comments to exchange with other users (instead of answers). I suggest you visit [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) page to have your accounts merged. This will allow you to comment on your own posts and on answers to your questions, until you have enough reputation to comment everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Please don't load your images inside of your `paintComponent()` Method, but put them in global variables instead.

Also, you should keep a global list or an array of all the rectangles you have in your game. Something like `ArrayList<Rectangle> blockList`. Then, in your `paintComponent()` or whatever method (where you check for collisions), loop over the list and check for collisions between the player and the individual rectangle:

```
for(Rectangle r : blockList) {
   if (playerHitbox.intersects(r)) {
      // Handle collisions here.
   }
}
```

Generally, I would advise you to read about the basics of game programming first, like making a proper structure (don't put everything in one class), proper game loops etc.

What if you started with something simpler than a Minecraft recreation? Thats way more fun than struggling with something too complicated. Just follow the prinicple "KISS": **K**eep **I**t **S**imple and **S**tupid. It will get complicated by itself.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I have another bug in the game. You can dig in the game but when the player moves the image of the dirt block moves too. It draws on every block that the player touches a dirt block because I said that it has to draw it on r.getX() and r.getY() and it changes every time the player moves. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @ProgrammerProgrammerIOSAN Always open up a new question for a new problem. If people try to answer multiple things in one SE-question things get very messy.
For everyone else: The "story" continues [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153119/making-minecraft-in-2d-blocks-move-when-player-moves).